# Angular - How to trigger keyboard events on button click?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have provided two separates button for Ctrl+z and Ctrl+y. I want the Ctrl+z and Ctrl+y functionality to be performed on the click of a button.
Here is my function.

```
undoText(event:MouseEvent){
    var element =   document.getElementById("undoBt")
     if(element){
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{composed: true, bubbles:true, cancelable:true, code:"ControlLeft", ctrlKey:true, key:'Control',keyCode:17, location:1}));
        element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{bubbles:true,   cancelable:true, code:"KeyZ", composed:true, ctrlKey:true, key:'z', keyCode: 90}));
       }

  }
```

Here is my html.

```
<mat-icon matTooltip="Undo"  (click)="undoText($event)" *ngIf="svgInit" id="btn1" class="undo" svgIcon="undo" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="undo">
        </mat-icon>
```

To achieve this, I am trying to trigger Ctrl+z and Ctrl+y on button click but they are not getting triggered and I'm not able to set isTrusted property true.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
(keyup.enter)="keyUpFunction($event)"
```

Where keyUpFunction($event) is your function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! but I want to trigger ctrl z keyboard event on button click

Comment: OKay for that you can use HostListener

Comment: I don't want to press key, only trigger ctrl+z onclick of button so may be HostListener will not be applicable

Comment: I need to apply the same functionality, have you applied it? @Dakopatel

Comment: Yes @AHMADEZZAT I applied it